# custom.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

when i am trying to move image to the center that time the browser can showing the error can not read property width of null . I am trying to divide the width of the screen by 2 i can t understan why that error is showing .

```
var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile");
var monitor = document.getElementById("monitor");
var tab = document.getElementById("tab");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var position = (screen.width - monitor.width)/2;
monitor.style.left = position+"px;";
function initScroll(){
  if(window.pageYOffset >500){
    mobile.style.left = "300px";
    tab.style.right = "250px";
    header.style.height = "60px";
    header.style.fontSize = "25px";
  }else{
    header.style.height = "60px";
    header.style.fontSize = "25px";
    mobile.style.left = "0px";
    tab.style.right = "0px";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll",initScroll);
```

```css
*{padding: 0;margin: 0;font-family:arial;}
#header{height:100px;background-color: #354458;font-size: 40px;color:#fff; text-align:center;line-height:2.5;
position:fixed; width:100%;z-index:20;
  -moz-transition: 2s height, 2s font-size;
  -o-transition: 2s height, 2s font-size;
   -webkit-transition: 2s height, 2s font-size;
   transition: 2s height, 2s font-size;
}
#banner{background: #3a9ad9;height:400px;position:fixed;width:100%;
top:100px;font-size:50px; text-align: center; color
  :#fff;z-index:10;
}
#banner > * {
  margin-top:30px;
}
#content{
  top:500px;
  position:relative;
  height:1000px;
  padding-top:200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index:15;
}
#mobile{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 470px;
  -moz-transition: 2s left;
  -o-transition: 2s left;
   -webkit-transition: 2s left;
   transition: 2s left;
}
#monitar{position: relative;}
#tab{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 385px; 
  -moz-transition: 2s right;
  -o-transition: 2s right;
   -webkit-transition: 2s right;
   transition: 2s right;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Java script Scroller</title>
  <meta  charset="utf-8"/>
  <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>
  <script src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
         <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="header">Header</div>
                <div id="banner">
                  <h1>My Animation</h1>
                  <h2>First collapsable header</h2>
                  <h3>Apurva Kinkar</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                   <img id="mobile" src="./img/1.jpg" />
                   <img id="monitar" src="./img/2.png" />
                   <img id="tab" src="./img/3.jpg" />
                </div>
         </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your img-id is called "monitar". There could be a typo

Comment: i am change that but its showing same error

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo error with your `<img>` declaration, It has to be `monitor` not `monitar`

```
 <img id="monitar" src="./img/2.png" />
```

Change this as,

```
 <img id="monitor" src="./img/2.png" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your image id is wrongly spelled.

Change this :-

```
<img id="monitar" src="./img/2.png" />
```

to

```
<img id="monitor" src="./img/2.png" />
```

After changing this, you will still get the same error. This is because, when your js code runs, the img element is still not added to the DOM. 
For that, make the javascript code run on document.ready function ( when the img with id "monitor" is present in the DOM ).

Here is the [working example](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/mABoRP) which uses jQuery's document.ready() function.

You can also use [this example](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/ZpXPZq) if your dont want to use jQuery.

Comment: Thanx but i cant understan why use The (function(){}

Comment: Its basically equivalent to `window.onload` . You can get more details about this in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Comment: @ApurvaKinkar I have edited my answer to make you understand better. Have a look :)

Comment: Yes it is working. i m recently start to working with animation using javascript